# how to count blinking LED flashes using arduino uno boards and LDR?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, sketch

i want to know code for counting the flashes of LEDs and display no. of flashes in particular time given.by using LDR.
basically i tried it with interrupts but i'm not getting it,so please help in this regard.

Comment: If you post the code of your attempt, we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An hardware solution could be achieved by putting a photodiode or a photoresistance near the flashing LED. Connect it to a pin that supports external interrupt and you're done. With a bit more circuitry you can ensure that the value on the pin doesn't oscillate: put a Schmit Trigger after the photodiode or resitance with its output on the input pin.

Comment: The Arduino Uno already has Schmitt triggers on all its digital inputs. C.f. figure 14.2 on page 76 of the [ATmega328P datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

LDRs only give an analog output, proportional to the amount of light.

To make it give a HIGH and LOW value, you have to tweak the other resistor used in the voltage divider.

Alternatively you could use `analogRead` and add a threshold value in your code.